# Expressão regular para extrair números de "200#5;300#10"

Tags: php, regex

Qual seria a melhor expressão regular para a seguinte entrada "200#5;300#10" ?

Comment: Depende do que queres selecionar... Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer?

Comment: O 200 significa o total de encomenda e 5 o desconto, o # é só o separador, ou seja primeiro total, depois # e depois desconto, e por fim ponto e virgula para separar de outra condição.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vai precisar de dois grupos de captura. Partindo do princípio que só tem digitos, podes usar assim:

```
/(\d+)#(\d+)/
```

O `\d` representa "dígito", e o `+` quer dizer "um ou mais". Os parenteses indicam grupos de captura, e o `#` indica exatamente o caracter `#`.

Um exemplo seria: http://ideone.com/wl3Q77

```
$string = "200#5;300#10";
preg_match_all('/(\d+)#(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

// resultado: 
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "200#5"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "300#10"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "200"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "300"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Valeu Sérgio! Obrigado pela explicação!