# Extrair informações de uma string

Tags: r, string

Tenho a seguinte string

Gostaria de extrair apenas os preços dentro dessa string

desde já agradeço

```
 a<-  " Scarpin Sofia Salto Bloco Slingback TurtleR$269,90   Scarpin Sofia 
 Nobuck Salto Bloco Slingback PretoR$269,90   Scarpin Sofia Nobuck Salto 
 Bloco Slingback Natural WoodR$269,90   Scarpin Sofia Nobuck Salto Bloco 
 Slingback New SalmonR$269,90   Scarpin Sofia Nobuck Salto Bloco Slingback 
 MandarineR$269,90   Scarpin Sofia Nobuck Salto Bloco Slingback 
 MostardR$269,90   Sandália Nobuck  Corda Salto Alto Gergelim e Verde LimeR$299,90  "
```

Comment: Tentou usar regex já?

Comment: ainda não, vou dar uma olhada, tem um exemplo por favor ?

Comment: Há varios exemplos pelo site, porém os principais( infelizmente nenhum em r) : [Extrair numeros de uma lista usando Regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37373/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-extrair-n%C3%BAmeros-de-200530010)  [Expressão regular para extrair números](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37373/expressão-regular-para-extrair-números-de-200530010)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode extrair os preços com uma combinação de `gregexpr` e de `regmatches`.

No que se segue tenho duas soluções a serem usadas consoante a estrutura dos preços no Brasil (sou Português).

Se um preço pode não ter a parte decimal, use esta primeira expressão regular.

```
m <- gregexpr("\\$[[:digit:]]+,{0,1}[[:digit:]]{0,2}", a)
regmatches(a, m)
#[[1]]
#[1] "$269,90" "$269,90" "$269,90" "$269,90" "$269,90" "$269,90"
#[7] "$299,90"
```

Se os preços têm sempre a vírgula seguida de dois algarismos, use esta segunda regex.

```
m <- gregexpr("\\$[[:digit:]]+,[[:digit:]]{2}", a)
regmatches(a, m)
#[[1]]
#[1] "$269,90" "$269,90" "$269,90" "$269,90" "$269,90" "$269,90"
#[7] "$299,90"
```

Answer (score 4):

Se precisar de um data.frame com os nomes e preços:

```
library(magrittr) # para os operadores de fluxo

dados <- strsplit(a, "(?<=[0-9] )", perl = TRUE) %>%
         unlist() %>%
         strsplit("R\\$") %>%
         do.call(rbind.data.frame, .)
names(dados) <- c("item", "preço")
```

E uma limpeza nos dados:

```
dados$item %<>% gsub("\n ", "", .) %>%
                gsub("  ", " ", .)

dados$preço %<>% gsub(" ", "", .) %>%
                 gsub(",", ".", .) %>%
                 as.character() %>%
                 as.numeric()

dados <- dados[complete.cases(dados), ]

> dados
                                                      item preço
1               Scarpin Sofia Salto Bloco Slingback Turtle 269.9
2         Scarpin Sofia Nobuck Salto Bloco Slingback Preto 269.9
3  Scarpin Sofia Nobuck Salto Bloco Slingback Natural Wood 269.9
4    Scarpin Sofia Nobuck Salto Bloco Slingback New Salmon 269.9
5     Scarpin Sofia Nobuck Salto Bloco Slingback Mandarine 269.9
6       Scarpin Sofia Nobuck Salto Bloco Slingback Mostard 269.9
7   Sandália Nobuck Corda Salto Alto Gergelim e Verde Lime 299.9
```